# At what resolution does Google Bot Web Crawlers consider desktop?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, googlebot

I'm aware that google evaluates how a site looks on mobile. At what resolution does google evaluate desktop sites?

My site uses a responsive layout up until 1200px width, at which point it shows and hides several elements. I want to know if google is seeing those elements I show at above 1200px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fairly small range of mobile device viewport sizes. Everything else will be regarded as "desktop". And:

> When the meta viewport element is absent, mobile browsers default to rendering the page at a desktop screen width (usually about 980px, though this varies across devices). [[source]](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/10/updating-our-technical-webmaster.html)

[Googlebot Smartphone is basically a mobile browser](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en), so should behave in the same way. Googlebot reads your CSS (assuming it's not blocked), and therefore your media queries.

> we see your content more like modern Web browsers, include the external resources, execute JavaScript and apply CSS. [[source]](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html)

Comment: To clarify, I shouldn't be concerned that desktop google bot web crawlers aren't seeing my desktop content at above 1200px?

Comment: What makes you think they aren't seeing it at that point?

Comment: In google webmaster tools for the desktop render and fetch it shows a image that says "This is how google bot sees the page". I want to know if that preview is meaningful. Appears to be about 960 width.

Comment: How is it _not_ meaningful? It's showing you a Googlebot rendering at a given viewport size. How do you get from there to thinking Googlebot can't see your content above 1,200px? CSS media queries neither allow nor prevent Google from reading your content. They read content from HTML and JavaScript. The CSS is a presentation layer, which Google can understand and process.

Comment: It's unclear if @Goose is asking about hiding content to boost ranking, or if the segmentation aspect of the new bot that can rank based on mobile/desktop content has a segment for larger view ports. If it's the latter, it does. If it's the first one, it's not a good topic to ask here.

Comment: @XOPJ There's no malicious SEO intent behind my question. My coworker believes 960px is "the desktop" view for google bot and above may not be acknowledged. Our media queries end at 1200px.

Answer (score 0):

If there's code showing min-width values of 1200px+ the crawler can detect and read that content just as it does for the mobile format content.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back this up? What if my element was hidden until 8000 pixel width, would google bot web crawlers knowledge that content as well?

Comment: Why are you hiding an element at 8k? That's so obscenely far out of users viewports even dual ultrawide monitors aren't going to see that.